# In Chef how can you pass attributes with "include_recipe"?

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, recipe

I need to call a recipe and pass it specific attribute data, like:

`include_recipe [nginx::passenger['my_attributeA' => 'foobar' , 'my_attributeB' => 'foofii']`

i.e. in my wrapper, I have to pass data to a called cookbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Node attributes in chef are global variables you should do this by setting them in the attributes file:

my_cookbook/attributes/default.rb:

```
default['my_attributeA'] = 'foobar'
default['my_attributeB'] = 'foofii'
```

my_cookbook/recipe/default.rb:

```
include_recipe "nginx::passenger"
```

my_cookbook/metadata.rb:

```
name "my_coobook"
version "1.2.3"

depends "nginx"
```

Note, gnerally you'd be setting node attributes like `default['nginx']['some_nginx_cookbook_attribute']` in your wrapper to control the nginx cookbook, you probably wouldn't be setting something arbitrary like `default['my_attributeA']`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to pass an argument for attribute assignment; rather, you will need to overload the attribute before including the desired recipe.

the attributes set in the dependent cookbooks before including other dependee cookbook, will be [merged](https://docs.chef.io/attributes/#about-deep-merge).

> if the attribute precedence levels are the same, then that data is merged. If the attribute value precedence levels in an array are different, then that data is replaced. For all other value types (such as strings, integers, etc.), that data is replaced.